# Java subclass calling superclass

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm having a little trouble with inheritance. What i have done is made a superclass as some of the attributes in the subclasses were identical.

I am trying to reference the superclass, I tried putting `super(name);` above the line `name = replacementName;`  it will not compile saying `name has private access in the Superclass 'person'.`  I know that it won't access a `private` field but how can I get the name from the superclass in a subclass method?

Here is the method.

```
public void changeName(String replacementName){
    name = replacementName;
}
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: Could you give the full class this code is part of? Your question itself does not clearly illustrate what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: We're going to need to see the superclass field declaration, but I think I know what the problem is. Just need to make sure!

Comment: if `name` in your super class is private, and there is no setter for it, then without breaking a lot of rules, there really isn't a way to do that.

Comment: If there is a name in the super class, then just move the `changeName` method to this class. Or call `super.setName(replacementName);` if there is a setter for `name` available.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options :

1 - In your super class, use private declaration for the name attribute and add public (or protected) getters/setters. Then you can modify your super class field from your child class using the setter method.

2 - In your super class, use protected declaration for your name field. Then you can access it directly from your child class.

...

Comment: You assume you have access to the super class. Assuming is not a good thing.

Comment: I read that he created the super and the child class together, so I assumed he could access it..

Comment: No he said, He made the super class which has same attribute and did a super to access it. And that itself is miss worded because he made a subclass, and try super(), because you can't super in a superclass to a subclass.